# how to delete java completely from windows

Tags: java, windows

I have messed up my windows java installation and i want to delete everything and re-install java , all of my java versions have been messed up and I don't know what to do in this situation
when I do:

```
C:\Users\LENOVO>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1

C:\Users\LENOVO>javac -version
javac 17.0.1

C:\Users\LENOVO>java -version
java version "1.8.0_311"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_311-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.311-b11, mixed mode, sharing)
```

**Why is java -version showing different things?**

I HAVE TRIED CHANGING PATH AND THERE IS NOTHING IN MY PATH RELATED TO JAVA 1.8.0.

I TRIED MANUALLY DELETING JAVA BUT IT ALWAYS SAID IT IS OPEN SOMEWHERE ELSE AND CLOSE THAT BEFORE MAKING ANY CHANGES HERE

Comment: Your path includes java 1.8 JRE.  You need to remove that from the path.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and visit the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

first of all you must go environment variables  and then delete all Java related paths and after that follow those links and delete them also from your local computer. It's done :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to fix the issue regarding it being open elsewhere but I'd recommend trying to open task manager to close Java that way.

As for uninstalling it, you can uninstall it as it is an app. Just open settings, go to apps, search Java, and uninstall it like so.